# PHP Jump Redirect

Tags: php, redirect, nginx

I'm trying to redirect users based on the query string on a php file. I created a php file go.php and pasted following code,

```
<?php
if ($v = 'AAAAA') {$link = 'https://example1.com/';}
if ($v = 'BBBBB') {$link = 'https://exapmle2.com/';}

header( 'Location: $link' ) ;
exit();
?>
```

I thought I will be able to redirect user to example1.com with mydomain.com/go.php?v=AAAAA
But it's not working. The script redirects user to mydomain.com/$link
Can anyone help me achieve this? I'm using nginx as webserver with php 7.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do something like this

```
$v = $_GET['V'];
if ($v == 'AAAAA'){
    $link = 'https://example1.com/';
}elseif ($v == 'BBBBB') {
    $link = 'https://exapmle2.com/';
}else{
   $link = false;  //you could output an error or put a default redirect in here instead.  Then you wouldn't need the second if condition ( with a default redirection )
}

if( $link ){
  header( "Location: $link" ) ;
  exit();
}
```

A few things to note:

- You are using assignment `=` not comparison `==` in your if condition.  In the original both conditions will pass with the end value of `$link` being the last one ( although its set in the first, the second replace it ), the `$v` variable will be set to equal `BBBBB` as well, nither of which is what you want.
- Variable interpolation ( automatic inserting the value ) only works when using double quotes not single quotes. `" $link "` vs `' $link '` the first will fill in the value of `$link` the second will literally be $link as a string.
- You have no default value if `$v` is not equal to either condition, what happens?
- You should use an `if` `elseif` because `$v` cannot be equal to both.  In the case it equals the first condition the rest are skipped, performance wise its better but something like that it dosn't matter so much, it's just best practice and more readable.

Comment: cool, I didn't even test it. But code this short I can run in my head...

Answer (score 0):

When you want to user variable inside header function please use double quotes 
`header("Location: $link") ;`

Also make sure that you are getting the value of url parameter using `$v = $_GET['v'];`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I'm new to this, I don't understand $v = $_GET['v']; part, where does it go?

Comment: First line of the php file.

Comment: Added it after <?php, but go.php?v=AAAAA redirects to exapmle2.com, but it should go to example1.com

Comment: You also have error in your code here is corrected code `if ($v == "AAAAA") {$link = "https://example1.com/";}
if ($v == "BBBBB") {$link = "https://exapmle2.com/";}`